# How to add new custom Rating&Review step after payment and review step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

1. I want to add an additional checkout step (Raing and Review) after
   the payment and review step.
2. if anyone knows the solution then please add a solution here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an official tutorial for that: [Add a New Checkout Step | Commerce PHP Extensions](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-new-step/).

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new module in app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]
> directory.

> Create a new KnockoutJS component in your module's
> view/frontend/web/js/view directory. This component will handle your
> new checkout step.

> Create a new HTML template file in your module's
> view/frontend/web/template directory. This file will contain the HTML
> for your new checkout step.

> Open the checkout_index_index.xml file (located in Magento's checkout
> module) and add your new KnockoutJS component to the checkout page.

> Add the necessary JavaScript to your new KnockoutJS component to
> handle form submission and validation.

> Create a new model and database table to save the customer's rating
> and review information.

> Finally, enable your new module in Magento and clear the cache to see
> your new checkout step in action.

Comment: I am trying this steps but checkout uses knockout js and html file.

Comment: Check My updated answer

Comment: I am new in magento So I am not understand how implement in code level

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: I have checked but not work